# Transpose only the matrix values with numpy if multiple of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, transpose

I have a 5x5 matrix and I would like to transpose all values but those which are multiple of 3, they will transpose with the following structure:

If multiple of 3:  `M[i, j] = (3 * j + i)**2`
Otherwise: `M[i, j] = M[j, i]`

`M` is the matrix, `i` and `j` the index of the rows and columns.

The matrix consists of 25 values from 1 to 100 without repetition.

I have the following code and now I have created the condition for the values that are multiple of 3. I don't know how to create the part where it should do:

```
M[i, j] = (3 * j + i)**2
```

I put 0 as a result just to show the spots where the `(3 * j + i)**2` should appear.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=25).reshape(5, 5)
print("Matrix 5x5 original")
print(M)
print("Matrix transposed")
M = np.transpose(M)
M[M % 3 == 0] = 0
print(M)
```

[image]

Comment: That code is incomplete.  Also I don't understand it.  `i` will be a row of `M`.  `np.transpose(M)` transposes the whole thing; why do that repeatedly?  And `i%3==0` is bound to raise an ambiguity error in the `if` expression.

Comment: Hi, hpaulj, yes, i is a row and j a column. The idea is that the matrix transpose the whole thing but those that are multiple of 3, they will show the result of M[i,j]=(3*j+i)**2

Comment: It's slightly unrelated, but you said in your post that the numbers should be without repetition. With `np.random.randint` it's not guaranteed. If "without repetition" is mandatory, you should use `np.random.choice(100, size=25, replace=False)`.

Comment: Many thanks Sams-studio. You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the mask `M % 3 == 0` to indices. Something like this should work:

```
M = M.T
i, j = np.where(M % 3 == 0)
M[i, j] = (3 * j + i)**2
```

Comment: I guess you need `np.where(M % 3 == 0)`.

Comment: @sams-studio. You're right. Fixed